# If $f(z)=v(x)+iu(y)$ is entire then $f$ is linear

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is entire and can be written as $f(z)=v(x)+iu(y)$, that is, the real part of $f$ depends only on $x=\Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$. Prove that $f(z)=az+b$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b\in\mathbb C$.

It's an easy exercise when we know that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable. In fact, we have $\forall z\in\mathbb C,\,f'(z)=\frac{dv}{dx}(x)$. Thus $f'$ is a real holomorphic function, hence constant and we can easily conclude that $\exists a\in\mathbb R,\,\exists b\in\mathbb C,\,f(z)=az+b$.

The problem is, I found this exercise at the chapter 2 of [A First Course in Complex Analysis](https://matthbeck.github.io/papers/complex.pdf). Up to chapter 2, they didn't talk yet about integration and didn't prove yet that holomorphicity is equivalent to analyticity to conclude that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable. So I'm curious about knowing how to solve this exercise without using these theorems or any other results of Cauchy's Integral Formula. Could you please help me?

Comment: Has the book covered the Cauchy-Riemann Equations at that point?

Comment: Suggestion - $f'(z)=v'(x)$ is also $u'(y)$, hence constant.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes it has covered the Cauchy-Riemann Equations.

Comment: @peterag  Yes you're right!! Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.MV Looking at peter a g comment, indeed it is easy since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. I wrote this equation without paying attention, my bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, we find that if $f=v(x)+iu(y)$, and $f$ is differentiable, then

$$v'(x)=u'(y) \tag 1$$

Inasmuch as the left-hand side of $(1)$ is independent of $y$ and the right-hand side is independent of $x$, then $v'(x)$ and $u'(y)$ are constants.  The result follows immediately.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark